# Run Apache 2.2 as a single httpd.exe for debugging

Tags: windows, apache, debugging, configuration, process

I'm running Apache 2.2 in console mode on Windows to test an apache module I'm writing.
By default, a parent httpd.exe is started (with one thread), which starts a child httpd.exe with a number of worker threads.

Now I have to attach the debugger to the child process each time to be able to debug my module.

Is there a way to configure Apache to run from a single httpd.exe? (Like good old days if I remember correctly) I've been searching the docs, but don't find anything else than limitations of the number of requests handles per thread or process...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use `httpd.exe -X` which will run apache as a single process without giving back terminal/cmd prompt control.

Comment: aah! it's called debug mode! should have thought of that. Thanks! (for future reference, -X is listed here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/httpd.html )